# Declaratively adding row and controls to grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Well, my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351209/dynamically-populate-a-form-with-data-from-database-and-add-rows-in-wpf) did not garner any response except a downvote, so I am going to break down the question and ask one elementary question at a time.

I have a WPF Application, in which there is a Grid (not DataGrid). Now I want to add rows to it at runtime. And in each of those rows will be a control like TextBox or Combobox. I understand this can be done by `RowDefinitions.Add(New RowDefinition())`, and then adding individual controls to each cell in the row, like we did in TableLayoutPanel in WinForms. But I was looking for a more elegant solution, where all controls with their event handlers would be added to the respective cells in a new row of the Grid when a button is clicked or an event is triggered. Is there any easy way to do it?

P.S. I also need to delete the rows as required, if that is a factor here. And the row deleted is not always the last row.

Comment: I've explained this many many many times already. Please search for "WPF ItemsControl MVVM" on StackOverflow.

Comment: I saw your solution in one of the previously answered questions, but it was too difficult for me to understand. I am completely new to WPF and have absolutely zero idea about MVVM. I'd be obliged if you could kindly point me towards a nice book to learn the fundamentals of MVVM and WPF. I have already visited Rachel's blog, but it didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The main idea is that you don't create or manipulate UI elements via code in WPF. Instead, you create a class that contains the data you want to show, and then a collection of that class, and use WPF's DataBinding features to "link" the UI with the data, so that the state of the UI reflects the state of the data at all times.

Comment: Thank you for succinctly explaining the concept. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it is better to use DataGrid to display data with repeating rows, not 
a Grid. But if you have special reasons to use a Grid, I have attached a code sample using a Grid, displaying in each row a Textbox, a ComboBox and a DeleteButton. An Add button allows to add new rows at the bottom and the DeleteButtons on every row allow the deletion of that row.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="GridAddRow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridAddRow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="AddButton" Content="Add"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GridAddRow {

  public partial class MainWindow: Window {

    int textCol, comboBoxCol, buttonCol;

    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();

      //initialise MainGrid, i.e. define columns, could be done in XAML
      addCol(out textCol, new GridLength(100));
      addCol(out comboBoxCol, GridLength.Auto);
      addCol(out buttonCol, GridLength.Auto);

      //initialise grid content, usually read from a db
      addRow("Some Text", 1);
      addRow("Another String", 3);

      AddButton.Click += AddButton_Click;
    }

    private void addCol(out int textCol, GridLength gridLength) {
      textCol = MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
      MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = gridLength });
    }

    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();

    private void addRow(string textBoxString, int comboBoxIndex) {
      int rowId = MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
      MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

      TextBox textBox = new TextBox { Text = textBoxString };
      textBoxes.Add(textBox);
      addControl(textBox, rowId, textCol);
      textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;

      ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox {SelectedIndex= comboBoxIndex };
      comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem {Content="0" });
      comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content="1" });
      comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content="2" });
      comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content="3" });
      comboBoxes.Add(comboBox);
      addControl(comboBox, rowId, comboBoxCol);
      comboBox.SelectionChanged += ComboBox_SelectionChanged;

      Button deleteRowButton = new Button {Content = "Delete"};
      addControl(deleteRowButton, rowId, buttonCol);
      deleteRowButton.Click += DeleteRowButton_Click;
    }

    private void addControl(Control control, int rowId, int textCol) {
      control.Tag = rowId;
      MainGrid.Children.Add(control);
      Grid.SetRow(control, rowId);
      Grid.SetColumn(control, textCol);
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
      TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
      int rowid = (int)textbox.Tag;
      //do something here. 
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
      ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
      int rowid = (int)comboBox.Tag;
      //do something here. 
    }

    private void DeleteRowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      Button deleteButton = (Button)sender;
      int rowid = (int)deleteButton.Tag;
      MainGrid.Children.Remove(deleteButton);

      TextBox textbox = textBoxes[rowid];
      MainGrid.Children.Remove(textbox);
      textBoxes.RemoveAt(rowid);

      ComboBox comboBox = comboBoxes[rowid];
      MainGrid.Children.Remove(comboBox);
      comboBoxes.RemoveAt(rowid);
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      addRow("", 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Saying "you should use MVVM" basically just means that you should create a class which has one property for every control (Textbox, Combobox) you use in your Window. Create a collection of that class with the data to be displayed, then bind it to the DataGrid, which will display the data and offers lots of functionality, which you have to program yourself when using a Grid. For more details see my article: [Guide to WPF DataGrid formatting using bindings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for :)